# Deleting data by location using another shapefile

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, overlapping-features, delete, duplication

I have two shapefiles: one is main file and another is a part divided (manually by selecting) from the main file.

Now i want to delete the divided part from the main file with the help of divided part. How this possible in QGIS?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you have two layers with overlapping objects.

Processing → Extract by location.

Extract features from the **main layer** by comparing them with features from **second layer**. The predicate is disjoint.
After launch, you'll get the layer without points from the second layer.

Answer (score 1):

If those overlapping features (points from the divided part) share the same location with features (points from the main layer) I will simply use the ["Difference"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#difference) from the `Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Difference`.

> This algorithm extracts features from the Input layer that fall
> outside, or partially overlap, features in the Overlay layer. Input
> layer features that partially overlap feature(s) in the Overlay layer
> are split along those features' boundary and only the portions outside
> the Overlay layer features are retained.
>
> Attributes are not modified, although properties such as area or length of the
> features will be modified by the difference operation. If such properties are
> stored as attributes, those attributes will have to be manually updated.